# Проблема со слайдером

Tags: jquery, slider, css

Есть такой плагин карусели unslider.js, не могу понять почему у меня не появляются навигационные точки (dots), глянул через фаербаг - точки есть, но их не видно

[jsfiddle.net/T3F6c/](http://jsfiddle.net/T3F6c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно позиционировать .dots абсолютно и не забыть указать, где он будет находиться.